# Getting repetitions of one in the base 2 representation of a number python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to enter a number in the input and get the number of occurrences of one in its **binary** basis

```
print(str({int(input()):'b'}).count('1'))
```

The code I wrote is like this, but for example:

```
input:3
output:0
```

That is wrong

Comment: `str({int(input()):'b'})` gives you `"{3:'b'}"`, not some binary. There is a [bin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bin) function for converting a number to binary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Proceed as follows:

```
   print("{:b}".format(int(input())).count('1'))

input:3
output:2
```

Comment: From Python 3.10... you can use `int.bit_count`... eg: `print(int(input()).bit_count())`.